# Angular 5 dynamically load directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular6, angular-template

I created a component, which houses a form control and it's surrounding ecosystem, aka. form error display logic, form control type, is it number, text, etc..

The idea is DRY, because I have over 20 forms on my application and I found out that I am repeating the same DOM code everywhere, because all the form controls are obviously basically the same and the containing DOM and error displaying logic is also the same. Thus I made a separate component out of the form input.

component HTML for demonstration of what I mean

```
<div [formGroup]="iFormGroup">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of formInputValidations">
        <div *ngIf="GLOBALS.doINeedToShowFieldError( iFormControlName, validation.validatorStr, iFormGroup, formSubmitted, true )"
             class="error-box error-box--brand-popup scale-show">
            {{ _formInputErrorTextService.getFormFieldErrorText( validation.errorMsgId ) }}
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input type="text"
               class="input"
               [(ngModel)]="iNgModel"
               formControlName="{{ iFormControlName }}"
        />
        <label>{{ title }}</label>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I hope this code is pretty self explanatory, meaning that there is a form-input component, which has configurable input options, which result in a standardized form input and it's surrounding code.

Where am I stuck?

Everything works as expected, but I need to start adding directives dynamically to the input. Meaning some inputs need to have a currency mask for example, so I would like to add an input option, aka. `isCurrency: boolean`, and if this is a currency, I would like to add an input mask directive to the input.

```
<input type="text"
       class="input"

       --> currencyMask <--

       [(ngModel)]="iNgModel"
       formControlName="{{ iFormControlName }}"
        />
```

Like this.

I know changing/adding directives dynamically is not supported in angular, but is there a way to somehow add them on the components bootstrapping period? Like with an *ngIf or so.

I tried making an `*ngSwitch="FormInputType.CURRENCY"`, but then it dawned on me that, I might not be able to simply categorize all the inputs with a single ENUM, because there might be directive combinations, aka currency with input required directive and currency without it, etc.

Any cool solutions?

Comment: i have a project which the fields are added and removed from backend, what i did is i used ngIf to check the input type, then i write the html code, i don't think there is another way anw

Comment: and oh, for the required attributes and name, id, or other attributes, just add them in the db table, meaning have for ex a table `fields`, then in that add the field type column, field name, required or not,etc

Comment: I don't really see an use in keeping fields in the database, other than to make them configurable in the backend. I might as well keep them as constants in the codebase, since only developers are allowed to change them at any given time. Also lessens the SQL load and backend code management.